# Groovy - Timeout function

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using below in my Jenkins pipeline and is not working. I want to pass time value in variable (time_val) and cannot hard code time

```
options {timeout(time: time_val, unit: 'MINUTES')}
```

Please let me know if I am running something wrong

Comment: why do you think `it's not working` ?

Comment: 11:29:26  Timeout expired 0 ms ago
11:29:26  Cancelling nested steps due to timeout - I see this message in console output

Comment: So timeout itself is working. You are passing something wrong as a parameter. Print the value and type of time_val right before timeout like this: `echo "${time_val.getClass()} - ${time_val}"`

Answer (score 0):

I declared variable as a global parameter and it worked.